# End point reference error while Calling Axis 2 Web Service

Tags: java, apache, apache-axis

We are getting the error below while calling an endpoint service of Apache Axis2.

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /Premium/services/PremiumCalc.PremiumCalcHttpsSoap11Endpoint/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

Please help to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were calling url directly in browser which is wrong style of calling endpoint web service. we call web service through SOAP API by passing web service WSDL file then it return our required results.